# Testing with Nx, Jest and Angular - Can't find library when running tests

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, nomachine-nx

I have an nx monorepo, which consists of two apps (client, server) and 5 libs (client-core, platform-core, etc). I pull the libraries into the Angular (client) application by setting the `paths` in the `tsconfig.json`.

```
    "paths": {
      "@myorg/platform-core": [
        "../../libs/platform-core/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@myorg/client-core": [
        "../../libs/client-core/src/index.ts"
      ],
    },
```

This works fine, The IDE is able to resolve the libraries and I can serve the application with `ng serve`. However when I attempt to test the angular application using `npx nx test client` then it can't find the libraries.

```
 FAIL  apps/client/src/app/core/guards/patient.guard.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    apps/client/src/app/core/guards/patient.guard.spec.ts:4:36 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@myorg/client-core' or its corresponding type declarations.

    4 import { EnvironmentService } from '@myorg/client-core';
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have tried adding the same paths into `tsconfig.spec.json` (which shouldn't be necessary as it `"extends": "./tsconfig.json"`) and that had no impact.

What do I need to do to access these libraries from my spec files?

Comment: Hi, you're supposed to mock the `EnvironmentService` (in the same specfile)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  I should still be able to access symbols from the libraries inside the specfiles. The `import { EnvironmentService } from '@myorg/client-core';` is inside the `paitent.guard.ts` file. It can find the libraries when I run `ng serve`, it should also be able to find the libraries when running `nx test`.

Comment: Same issue - did you find a solution?

Comment: A colleague did and I can't recall what the solution was. It was a very out of the box "that was too simple" solution. I'll report back if it strikes me.

Answer (score 0):

What versions do you use? I had the same problem on Angular 12 with jest 28.  When I upgraded all my dependencies to Angular 14 + jest 28 the problems were gone. As a tip: using yarn workspaces also makes the resolves easier without having to use the `paths` property.

If the versions are up to date `nx` also has some problems with application-specific paths it seems. There is a (closed) issue about it:

> For reference to people having issues with "Module not found" error.
> Provided tsconfig.app.json's baseUrl directs to application source, where it seems that it should direct to workspace root. For me links between modules started working when I either removed the baseUrl from tsconfig.app.json or pointed it to worspace root.
> Your tsconfig.json (or in latest nx it's tsconfig.base.json) that lives in workspace root should still have the baseUrl and it seems to be correct.

See https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/738

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be that in your `jest.json` add the path to the library as you did in the `tsconfig.json`, for example:

```json
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@myorg/client-core": "<rootDir>/../../libs/client-core/src/index.ts"
  }
```

- please note that you must add `<rootDir>` like that, then add the path to the index file or src dir.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the following solution worked. 
Instead of running unit tests with `npx nx test client`, specify the project name as follows:

```
npx nx test nx-project-name --test-file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts
```

or, if you want to test libraries,

```
npx nx test nx-project-name --test-file=libs/lib-name
```

Disclaimer: It works with Nx Standalone apps but since the project name and the path is explicit it should work with monorepo as well.